# How to give keyboard focus to a pop-up Gtk.Window

Tags: gtk

I have a pop-up window (created using the WINDOW_POPUP type) which contains some widgets on it, including a text entry. The problem is that the entry doesn't get the focus when I click on it, so I can't type anything. Is there any flag I have to set to allow the window to get the keyboard focus?

Answer (score 6):

You can not use WINDOW_POPUP for gtk-windows that require the focus. Instead you should use a GtkWindow with type GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL and call the next functions (or methods)

```
GtkWindow *result = g_object_new(GTK_TYPE_WINDOW, "type", GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL, NULL);
gtk_widget_set_can_focus(result, TRUE);
gtk_window_set_decorated(GTK_WINDOW(result), FALSE);
gtk_window_set_type_hint(GTK_WINDOW(result), GDK_WINDOW_TYPE_HINT_POPUP_MENU);
gtk_window_set_transient_for(GTK_WINDOW(result), main_top_level_window);
```

This worked for me ... unfortunately the icon in the window-list blinks short when this 'popup' is destroyed

Answer (score 1):

Despite the previous answers and the GTK Reference, it is possible to grab the keyboard focus when using a GTK_WINDOW_POPUP. You need to connect to the "show" event...

```
GtkWindow *w = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_POPUP);
g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(w), "show", G_CALLBACK(on_window_show), NULL);
```

... with a callback that tries to grab the keyboard:

```
static void on_window_show(GtkWidget *w, gpointer user_data) {
    /* grabbing might not succeed immediately... */
    while (gdk_keyboard_grab(w->window, FALSE, GDK_CURRENT_TIME) != GDK_GRAB_SUCCESS) {
        /* ...wait a while and try again */
        sleep(0.1);
    }
}
```

That works for me pretty well.

Comment: This will grab the keyboard exclusively. Clicking on other programs' windows with the mouse will not transfer the keyboard focus to them. There might be work around, but I am not aware of any.

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

static gboolean delete_event( GtkWidget *widget,
                              GdkEvent  *event,
                              gpointer   data )
{
    g_print ("delete event occurred\n");
    gtk_main_quit ();
    return TRUE;
}

static void destroy( GtkWidget *widget,
                     gpointer   data )
{
    gtk_main_quit ();
}

int main( int   argc,
          char *argv[] )
{
    GtkWidget *window;
    GtkWidget *windowpopup;
    GtkWidget *button;

    gtk_init (&argc, &argv);

    /* create a new window */
    window = gtk_window_new (GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
    windowpopup = gtk_window_new (GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
    gtk_window_set_transient_for(GTK_WINDOW(windowpopup),GTK_WINDOW(window));
    gtk_window_set_destroy_with_parent(GTK_WINDOW(windowpopup),TRUE); 
    gtk_widget_show (windowpopup);

    g_signal_connect (G_OBJECT (window), "delete_event",
              G_CALLBACK (delete_event), NULL);
    g_signal_connect (G_OBJECT (window), "destroy",
              G_CALLBACK (destroy), NULL);

    /* Creates a new button with the label "Hello World". */
    button = gtk_button_new_with_label ("Hello World");

    g_signal_connect_swapped (G_OBJECT (button), "clicked",
                  G_CALLBACK (gtk_widget_destroy),
                              G_OBJECT (window));

    gtk_container_add (GTK_CONTAINER (window), button);

    gtk_widget_show (button);
    gtk_widget_show (window);

    gtk_main ();

    return 0;
}
```