# C++ GTK 3: Get keyboard focus to window

Tags: c++, focus, gtk3

I am trying to close a GTK window by pressing <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>q</kbd> on Mac OS or <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>F4</kbd> on Windows.

The code below works fine if I click into the window once – if I do not click, all commands are passed to the underlying terminal. So e.g. if I press <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>q</kbd>, my Terminal will ask me if I want to close it (the terminal). But as soon as I click into the window using the mouse pointer, I can use <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>q</kbd> to close this window. It feels weird that the windows do not gain focus on startup, as I feel all my normal applications do gain focus for keyboard inputs on startup.

**main.cpp**

```cpp
// Copyright 2017 Sebastian Höffner

#include "gtk/gtk.h"


namespace {

static void cb_key_press(GtkWidget* widget, GdkEventKey* event_key) {
  switch (event_key->keyval) {
    case GDK_KEY_F4:
      if (event_key->state & GDK_MOD1_MASK) {
        gtk_main_quit();
      }
      break;
    case GDK_KEY_q: case GDK_KEY_W:
      if (event_key->state & GDK_META_MASK) {
        gtk_main_quit();
      }
      break;
  }
}

}  // namespace

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

  GtkWidget* window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);

  g_signal_connect(window, "key-press-event", G_CALLBACK(::cb_key_press), NULL);
  g_signal_connect(window, "destroy", G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit), NULL);

  gtk_window_fullscreen(GTK_WINDOW(window));
  gtk_window_present(GTK_WINDOW(window));

  gtk_main();

  return 0;
}
```

**CMakeLists.txt**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)

# Project options
project(gtk_test VERSION 0.1 LANGUAGES CXX C)

find_package(PkgConfig)
pkg_check_modules(GTK gtk+-3.0)

include_directories(${GTK_INCLUDE_DIRS})
link_directories(${GTK_LIBRARY_DIRS})
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${GTK_LIBRARIES})
```

To compile, put both files (`CMakeLists.txt` and `main.cpp`) into the same directory, and follow these commands:

```sh
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ..
make
```

You can then start the program `./gtk_test` (it is located in `build`).

*Some more background*

I initially started out by modifying the [Getting started example](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/gtk-getting-started.html) but quickly found that using a `GtkApplication` seems to be overkill for my application (which basically should only show fullscreen images, thus OpenCV's highgui is not good enough without the Qt backend), so I adapted `gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);` which I found on various answers and tutorials.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4026272/3004221) to [How to give keyboard focus to a pop-up Gtk.Window](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1925568/3004221) explains how to gain exclusive keyboard access for an application, but I only want to have keyboard focus when I start the application.

**UPDATE**: Added CMakeLists.txt and removed the generated compilation messages. Added explanations on how to compile and run.

Comment: Try some of the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9054462/how-do-i-raise-a-window-that-is-minimized-or-covered-with-pygobject) and let me know how it works.

Comment: I tried `gtk_window_set_keep_above(GTK_WINDOW(window), true);` before, I stumbled over the same question. I just tried it again, but it does not what I want. I assume it takes care of the window staying topmost, which "fullscreen" windows do anyways on MacOS. What I want is to have the keyboard focus transferred from the calling Terminal to the new window.

Comment: Have you also tried the `gtk_window_present()` ?

Comment: Yes, it is part of the code above.

Comment: My bad. I do see that you have no `gtk_widget_show_all()` for the main window.

Comment: I don't have it in that simple example because that will only make all widgets contained in the window visible, in a more complex example I am using it. But I also tried it for this example now, unfortunately it is still not working properly.

Comment: There used to be a `gtk_window_raise()` or something like that, but I can't find any reference for it. Sadly, it seems I am running out of suggestions.

Comment: Thank you for trying to help still, it's highly appreciated!

Comment: One more suggestion : maybe it is a [focus](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkWindow.html#gtk-window-set-accept-focus) problem.

Comment: I tried, with no success. Maybe it's because the default is [`true`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkWindow.html#GtkWindow--accept-focus) already. My bet is currently [`has-toplevel-focus`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkWindow.html#GtkWindow--has-toplevel-focus), but it's a read-only property. Maybe I can set it via a GtkBuilder with a ui xml file. Thanks again for your input.

Comment: Stays read-only, even with a GtkBuilder and a UI file.

Comment: How are you compiling this example? I use Linux and Python so I need some help in trying to duplicate your problem.

Comment: I updated the example to provide a CMakeLists.txt and build instructions.

Comment: It works properly for me on Linux. How about another [focus](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkWindow.html#gtk-window-set-focus-on-map).

Comment: I tried it, no change. According to [glade](https://glade.gnome.org) it seems to be the default anyways. But then I guess it's an OS issue. Will try it on a linux machine soon as well.